# Summing rows of a matrix based on column index

Tags: r, matrix, apply, tapply, rowsum

I am trying to go from a matrix that has columns that "belong together" to one where the row-sums of the relevant sub-matrices have been formed. I.e. going from

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17   21   25   29   33    37    41    45    49    53    57    61
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18   22   26   30   34    38    42    46    50    54    58    62
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19   23   27   31   35    39    43    47    51    55    59    63
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40    44    48    52    56    60    64
```

to

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   30   46  185  220
[2,]   18   32   48  190  224
[3,]   21   34   50  195  228
[4,]   24   36   52  200  232
```

I assume there must be some much more elegant and faster way to do this than by looping over the indices as I do below (particularly, my real matrix would be more like 4000 by many thousands).

`example <- matrix(1:64, nrow=4)
 myindex <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
 summed <- matrix( rep(unique(myindex), each=dim(example)[1]), nrow=dim(example)[1])
 for (i in 1:length(unique(myindex))){
    summed[,i] <- apply(X=example[,(myindex==i)], MARGIN=1, FUN=sum) 
 }`

It is probably my lack of experience with apply and tapply that prevents me from figuring this out. A fast dplyr approach would of course also be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a one liner with `sapply`:

```
sapply(unique(myindex), function(x) rowSums(example[, which(myindex == x), drop = FALSE]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   30   46  185  220
[2,]   18   32   48  190  224
[3,]   21   34   50  195  228
[4,]   24   36   52  200  232
```

We let `sapply` loop over all unique values of `myindex`, and use `which` to define the columns which should be included into the `rowSums`.

---

Edit: Included `drop = FALSE` to prevent single indexes from simplifying to vector. Thanks @mt1022 for pointing out the bug!

Comment: Thank you for one of the quick responses on my 4000 by 3020 example it seems consistently the fastest out of the 3 proposed answers, so I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can also do this by `split`ting

```
sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(example), myindex), rowSums)
#     1  2  3   4   5
#[1,] 15 30 46 185 220
#[2,] 18 32 48 190 224
#[3,] 21 34 50 195 228
#[4,] 24 36 52 200 232
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach...

```
example <- matrix(1:64, nrow=4)
myindex <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)

summed <- t(apply(example,1,cumsum))
summed <- summed[,cumsum(rle(myindex)$lengths)]
summed[,-1] <- t(apply(summed,1,diff))
summed

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   30   46  185  220
[2,]   18   32   48  190  224
[3,]   21   34   50  195  228
[4,]   24   36   52  200  232
```

Answer (score 2):

An altenative approach with matrix multiplication (less efficient for large dataset):

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow = ncol(example), ncol = max(myindex))
x[cbind(1:ncol(example), myindex)] <- 1
example %*% x

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   15   30   46  185  220
# [2,]   18   32   48  190  224
# [3,]   21   34   50  195  228
# [4,]   24   36   52  200  232
```

Here is a benchmark with the an example data matching the real data size:

```
library(microbenchmark)

n_row <- 4000
n_col <- 3020
example <- matrix(rnorm(n_row * n_col), nrow = n_row)
myindex <- ceiling((1:n_col)/5)

microbenchmark(
    matrix = {
        x <- matrix(0, nrow = ncol(example), ncol = max(myindex))
        x[cbind(1:ncol(example), myindex)] <- 1
        example %*% x
    },
    split = {  # by akrun
        sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(example), myindex), rowSums)
    },
    which = {  # by LAP
        sapply(unique(myindex), function(x) rowSums(example[, which(myindex == x)]))
    },
    times = 10
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
#  matrix 982.55727 989.65177 992.7295 992.91230 997.3704 999.0066    10
#   split 162.13377 162.57711 194.5668 167.92963 182.5335 403.8740    10
#   which  90.28227  94.82681 119.3977  96.03701 103.1125 316.9170    10
```

Comment: Thank you. The microbenchpackage is really interesting. Interestingly with my real example (4000 by 3020), I ended up with
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      lq       mean     median         uq
 matrix 13040.5662 13535.0503 13874.2902 14135.7251
 split  2379.6066  3173.5876  2631.1031  3371.2384
 which  204.2357   322.9715   254.2363   383.8717

Comment: @Björn, It seems the matrix approach is too slow on the real dataset. I thought is should be faster.